# Determining which static libraries are linked unnecessarily

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I want to cut down library dependencies on some C++ executables I'm compiling for Linux with GCC. There is a list of probably 40 static libraries that being linked. I want to determine which ones are unnecessary, and I would rather not try removing them one at a time to find out.

Is there an option in GCC to make it warn about libraries that are linked but don't resolve any symbols?

Are there any Linux tools available that will help me out?

To be clearn, I'm not concerned with unused code being linked into the executable. Rather, I'm concerned with the unnecessary build dependencies. I'd like to cut down my build times.

Comment: Normally, gcc will call `ld` with `--as-needed` enabled (the default) and only libraries will be linked that resolve symbols. For gcc you could use `-Wl,--as-needed` (before any of the libraries) to make sure...

Comment: @Elijan9 To be clear, I'm not actually concerned with the code bloat. I don't think the code for unused libs is being linked in anyway. I'm more concerned with the build times due to unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: My understanding is that linkers will only include code from *static* libraries as necessary.  Usually code that isn't referenced is not placed into the executable.

Comment: Look at the *map* file generated by the linker.  It should tell you which libraries were included into the executable.  You could remove the unused libraries from your build.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Hey that sounds promising. Do you have any advice? This could be made into a full answer.

Comment: My advice is to have the linker print out the map or cross-reference document and look at it.  I've written small programs that parse map files looking for symbols, so searching for library names shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on top of the information provided by @ThomasMatthews in a comment to the question:

Run the linker with the `-M` option and pipe its output to the following script:

**get_used_libs**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -e '/^Discarded input sections$/,$ d'                                   \
-e '/^Archive member included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)$/ d'    \
-e '/^As-needed library included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)$/ d' \
-e '/^Discarded input sections$/ d'                                         \
-e '/^$/ d; /^\s/ d; s/\s\+.\+//; s/(.\+//'                                 \
| sort -u
```

It will return the list of the libraries that were **necessary** for your program to link.

Disclaimer: The script was only tested on output from `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.25.1` on a toy program.

Answer (score 1):

While not as convenient as the other answer, you can use `nm` to list the required (`U`) and exported (anything else, but beware of `[VvWw]`) symbols for any object or archive.

A little preprocessing with grep and/or sed might make this more helpful for some use cases.